# Add float type with separator "." to database sql

Tags: sql, database, model-view-controller

I have in my table in database float type. And when i add record to database using entity framework separator float value is "." but sql need ",". What can i do that change this that i can add record with separator "." to sql?

I programming in mvc 5.

Comment: What do you mean with "separator"?

Comment: I want that float type in database will be example 14.545 instead 14,545 :)

Comment: Try to use decimal instead of float.

Comment: I don't know any system that handles floats with comma. I come from Germany and we indicate fractions with commas but a float is always with a dot. What system do you use and what settings did you change? Entity framework sounds like C#.

Comment: I come from Poland. I didn't changed nothing. I have orginally settings. You now where i can change it?

Comment: Ok i repair it. I add in web.config
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />